# Digital signing of VBA project under Windows 10

Tags: vba, outlook, certificate, digital-signature, windows-10

Yesterday I upgraded from win 8.1 to win 10. In Outlook 2013 under win 8.1 I had a VBA script (macro) which was automatically adding BCC to every mail I have sent. This script was digitally signed so that I can have the Macro setting like this: "Notifications for digitally signed macros, all other macros disabled" without asking me to enable this macro every time I start the Outlook. Now it doesn't work any more. The script is working well if I set this macro security setting to: "Enable all macros" - but I don't want to use this setting because of security reasons.

So obviously the problem is somewhere in digital signing of the VBA script. I did it all from the beginning: I removed the previous certificate, created new one using the SELFCERT.EXE, and did all the procedure like with win 8.1 and everything went well like described [here](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/selfcert.htm) except that part in which it should ask only for the first time if I trust the publisher and I should check "always trust macros from this publisher". I cannot invoke this window. Maybe this points out to some problem or inconsistency: it should show this window for me to check it but is not showing because I previously under win 8.1 already have checked it...?

Has anybody some idea how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Well, if the publisher cannot be trusted then the signing will indeed have little effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it finally!

The only thing I had to do was to run Outlook as administrator. As soon as I did that, the window with "trust all documents from this publisher" appeared and after I clicked it everything after that worked like before.

Comment: So you have to run Outlook as Administrator EVERY time?

Comment: I only had to run as administrator the first time. After that I could run Outlook normally (not as administrator) and the macros continued working without prompts or other shenanigans

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading from Windows 7 x32 to Windows 10 but with Outlook 2010 rather than 2013.  Tried all sorts of thing without success.

What eventually worked for me was to go into the Trust Center, Macro Settings, and check the box "Apply macro security settings to installed add-ins" as well as the 'Notifications for digitally signed macros' option.

The 'Disable all macros' option gets greyed out.

Click OK and exit Outlook.

Next time you open Outlook you will be asked to accept each of the installed add-ins as well as your self-certified VBA project - but this is a one-time requirement.  As belt and braces I allowed it to install the certificates automatically.  In my case at least, from then on all my macros ran normally :-)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort.Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I did as you said but nothing happens. When I closed and again opened the Outlook it didn't ask me to accept installed add-ins (it didn't ask anything). The only thing which I have noticed was that with this option checked I can't open Visual Basic editor from the inside of Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this thread is dated, but I discovered the reason Bzek's solution worked.  I don't want to run Outlook as an Administrator, but I also did want my macros to function as they had in W7.  The potential solution from Kopweb didn't work for me.

The good news is that a simple check box click in the Advanced section of the Cert properties for 'client authentication' did the trick.  Restart Outlook normally and the macros should work.  See the image below:
[Cert - Advanced Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWsGH.png)